# Why `T extends "A"` and `S extends "A"` have no overlap?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm confused with a typescript compile error abut the following code:

```js
function f<T extends "A", S extends "A">(x: T, y: S) {
  if (x === y) {
     // ERROR: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T' and 'S' have no overlap. ts(2367)
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEAiAQVIBpEBlLXfYsygPgApsAuRNGgTx60AlIgDeAWABQiRDGCJOiALyrE-UZJmzZAel2IAogCVjAeWM80ACxgkICAjFgJEAdxgAbT4gCGnt19+EgAnTCgQEKQAcmB-IkxoxCIYSExEKGt0qH4AB0wSaLQk30JEaNok618AN3SwOEQ4OpDPX1yAOigidgAmAGYANgB2YWlZAF9pCaA)

Obviously, `T` and `S` could have overlap, but the compiler says they have no overlap. Why  does this happen and how to resolve this error?

Comment: Intresting situation. Could you please give more descreptive example? I can't image how you could use `extends <literal>`

Comment: Couldn't find any documentation about extending literal types

Comment: What I want to do is something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UBEBBJUA+yBCSDcAsAFCiRQByAhgLYQA8KUEAHsBAHYAmAzrADRRsTVhx6wAfAigADACQBvFAF8AtAu7AATgEt2AcyUBiBdlXqtug9MJEAZgFd2AY2DaA9uyjbuVWnQAqwmxcvDACAMpBoqHiABTMAFxQ-gIgSeEC7DQQSRo6+gCUSb70KVDhkvLEUF62UPEI8IggBVBVRDVKxEpAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27910#issuecomment-454894288) by RyanCavanaugh also applies to your case:

> === is only allowed between two operands if there is a "comparable" type relationship between them. This is similar to the check that determines if a type assertion is legal, with some extra special cases.

To see a more meaningful error from the compiler, try a cast:

```js
function f<T extends "A", S extends "A">(x: T, y: S) {
  /**
   * Conversion of type 'T' to type 'S' may be a mistake 
   * because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. 
   * If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
   * 
   * 'T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'S',
   * but 'S' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"A"'.
   */  
  const a = x as S;
}
```

To make the compiler happy, you can convert to `unknown` or `any`.

```js
  if (x as unknown === y) {
    return true;
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEAiAQVIBpEBlLXfYsygPgApsAuRNGgTx60AlIgDeAWABQiRDGCJOiAIYlwAazBwA7kgC8exP1GSZs8wCdMUEBaRQLITAG5psgL5vEVm3eTKAGyIXaU8paQgEIihkODhEQwpSVylIsCI4AMwAOgC4AHN2AHIrIhAAqCKaYHZgOOq44WEUoA)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure, whether I get you right. But maybe this could help you

```js
type T = `${'A' | 'B'}-${string}`;

function isName(x: T, y: T, name: string): `${T}#${T}` {
    if (x === y) { // no errors here
    }
    return 'A-first#B-second'; // valid
    return 'A-first#C-second'; // is not valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not enough because it doesn't restrict the type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UAGASA3gcgIIagHygwCEMBfAWnQGdgAnASwDsBzUpAbgChOAzAV0YBjYPQD2jKPSoA5AIYBbCAAoAHgC5YAGiggNMbYwUQNNBiwCUG1GhikAxOltIoaTlHdRgAC1qiA7lAAorS+tEoAROHmnKTcguI0UOrIWJRopkysdkRpGSxsCJIyRkrY5DyiohjaxOQARrK01YSpFaLZ9Y0Y5uxAA